# NameError (uninitialized constant) when trying to call method from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, rails-console

I wanna use [harvested gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/harvested) in one of my models. It's installed (no issues), `bundle check` says it's ok. It works from `rails console` but somehow not from model. Any hints?

```
def get_clients
  harvest = Harvest.hardy_client('foo', 'bar', 'baz') 
end
NameError (uninitialized constant HarvestForm::Harvest):
  app/models/harvest_form.rb:23:in `get_clients'
  app/controllers/api/v1/harvest_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

Comment: Did you restart the server after adding the gem?

Comment: nope :) wanna change this comment into answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restart the server :)